# Nodemailer connection timeout when running in docker container

Tags: docker, nodemailer

I'm facing a problem with Nodemailer running inside a docker container. It works fine with my development environment (running directly on my local machine). That seems to not work when I start my server inside docker container. I already tried to export these ports from docker container: 25, 465, 587, but it is still not working.

Message of error:

`error Error: Connection timeout at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19) at SMTPConnection._onError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20) at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22) at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17) at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) { code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }`

this is my smtp config:

```
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    user: process.env.USER,
    pass: process.env.PASS
  };
```

Thanks for any solutions to solve that problem.

Comment: any update on this error ?

Comment: in my case vps provider blocks email ports: 25, 465, 587 и 2525. He says it's for security reasons.